# Issue with using "this" statement to get current value

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, truffle, ethereumjs, ether-pudding

I am trying to get the current value for my int variable `counterforindex` in the check function. However this doesn't seem to happen.

```
uint public counterforindex;

function Check(string hdata, string dtime) returns(bool out1)

{

    uint C1 = 0; 
    C1 = this.counterforindex; //The error occurs here
......
}
```

The error is as follows

```
Error: Type function () returns (uint256) is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256.
        C1 = this.counterforindex;
```

Any solution guys?????

Answer (score 2):

Adding parenthesis as `C1 = this.counterforindex();` should do the trick as explained on this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649753/how-to-achieve-simple-oop-in-solidity)